# Page history - back button exists?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible check if there is a value for history.go(-1)? I know you can't access history.previous directly.

I am trying to stay away from document.referrer because I know it can be blocked in some instances.

Here is what I am trying to do. I have an error page, on this page I would like to either have a BACK button (if it's not the only item in history) or a close button (if it is).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (history.length) {
    //There is history to go back to
    history.go(-1);
}
```

Comment: Ha, duh! Sometimes it's the easiest answer.

Comment: Is there any way of checking whether the forward button exists?

Comment: does this check if previous page was `about:newtab` or not ;)

Comment: This is NOT correct because `history.length` includes not only back pages but also forward pages. So if you open a browser tab, follow link, click "back" the history length will be more then zero while you can't go back again.

Comment: @Finesse I really don't know how this answer can be so voted

Comment: this will not work for pages loaded in new tab, so i made this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68161306/1348517

Answer (score 15):

Actually, `history.length` is always one or more, since the current page counts. Also, if you have a forward history (i.e. you used the back button), those pages also count. So you need a more complicated check:

```
if( (1 < history.length) && document.referrer ) {
```

Comment: Is there any way of checking whether the forward button exists?

Comment: Referrer is passed if `target="_blank"` link is clicked and you can't do "back" in a new tab, so this solution is not perfect.

Comment: @Finesse is right so i made this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68161306/1348517

Answer (score 4):

There is no cross-browser approach to accomplish this. Document.Referrer may be set even if no history entry exists.

I came up with the following "hack". It utilizes the onbeforeunload event to detect whether the browser starts leaving the page or not. If it does not in a certain timespan it'll just redirect to the fallback.

```
window.goBack = function goBack(fallback){
  var useFallback = true;
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    useFallback = false;
  }
  window.history.back();

  setTimeout(function(){
    if (useFallback){ window.location.href = fallback; }
  }, 100); 
}
```

You can call this function using `goBack("fallback.example.org")`.

One of the use cases is that you may want to add a back button to any page and also want to make sure that this back button works even if the user goes directly to this page (e.g. by bookmark, direct link etc).

So either it does perform a history.back() or if there is no entry, it'll redirect to a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

If the history has a length greater than 0, then it contains at least one history point.

```
if (history.length)
```

Comment: yeah and that history point could be `about:newtab` too right?

Answer (score -1):

```
 function test() {
        document.URL = document.referrer;            
    }
```