# How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not

Tags: javascript

I want using JavaScript to see if there is history or not, I mean if the back button is available on the browser or not.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417084/js-onclick-history-go-1-only-if-under-my-domain

Comment: If your purpose is to check `goback` is work, I think you can setup a timer after the goback call ... so you can redirect to a fallback link if the `goback` not work.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Technically there is an accurate way, which would be checking the property:

```
history.previous
```

**However, it won't work.** The problem with this is that in most browsers this is considered a security violation and usually just returns **undefined**.

```
history.length
```

Is a property that others have suggested...
**However**, the length doesn't work completely because it doesn't indicate **where** in the history you are.  Additionally, it doesn't always start at the same number.  A browser not set to have a landing page, for example, starts at 0 while another browser that uses a landing page will start at 1.

[image]

Most of the time a link is added that calls:

```
history.back();
```

or

```
 history.go(-1);
```

and it's just expected that if you can't go back then clicking the link does nothing.

Comment: This is good info, but it does not resolve the problem. It'd be to elaborate some code that actually works on any browser. Perhaps a code that first checks the browser you are using.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is not a definitive answer. You are saying the pros and cons of each approach but not how to get a script that checks what browser you are using and conditionally execute one or the other pieces of code.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by 
'The problem with this is that in most browsers this is considered a security violation'
Another user in another thread also pointed that being able to get client's browser history is violating the security, but doesn't explain why is that. Can anyone give some example what are the security threats?

Comment: A website shouldn't be able to know a user's history which could include indirect personal information. A site can use tracking/cookies to know what the user is doing on the site itself but they shouldn't, for example, be allowed to figure out what bank I use, which school my kids go to, etc... Therefore, the browsers won't allow access to that property

Comment: I have added an way to detect it using the history state, it allows you to detect if you are on the first url state

Comment: TL;DR version: `history.length > 1 ? history.back() : location.href='/';`

Answer (score 106):

There is another way to check - check the referrer. The first page usually will have an empty referrer...

```
if (document.referrer == "") {
    window.close()
} else {
    history.back()
}
```

Comment: Referrer can be hidden for privacy reasons.

Comment: The referrer is always empty when a page was not loaded by a link but by entering the URL into the address bar, or loading a bookmark. Such pages can sure have a history though, when the browser tab/window had loaded another page before!

Comment: But is applicable solution for navigation across the multipage website

Comment: Does not work if a window was opened with target="_blank" to force a new window.  The back button on the browser won't work, but there will be a document.referrer

Comment: or if i right click and open it in new window. The browser's back button is disabled, but the document.refererr points to the previous page

Comment: Works perfectly for redirecting from an iOS shortcut that isn't a web app.

Comment: This will not work if you are coming from a secure (HTTPS) page to an insecure page (HTTP), as that will strip the referrer.

Comment: `window.close()` is considered a security risk by many modern browsers. Some just wont let you do it. Better to redirect to a fall-back URL.

Comment: Referrer is passed if browser tab is opened via `target="_blank"` link.

Comment: that's a good idea. I ended up with server side `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: No it is not working. it's always empty for my use cases. There is history for the current website and the user navigates within the same site. The referrer is still empty.

Answer (score 74):

My code let the browser go back one page, and if that fails it loads a fallback url. It also detect hashtags changes.

When the back button wasn't available, the fallback url will be loaded after 500 ms, so the browser has time enough to load the previous page. Loading the fallback url right after `window.history.go(-1);` would cause the browser to use the fallback url, because the js script didn't stop yet.

```
function historyBackWFallback(fallbackUrl) {
    fallbackUrl = fallbackUrl || '/';
    var prevPage = window.location.href;

    window.history.go(-1);

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        if (window.location.href == prevPage) {
            window.location.href = fallbackUrl; 
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I think this really nails the heart of the question, the why a person cares and what can actually be done about it in a reliable manner and consistent.

Comment: This worked until I took the url where the back-button resides and pasted it in a new tab in chrome. Clicking on the back-button resulted in being sent to an empty tab. :(

Comment: That's Chrome's default behaviour. You "visited" the page `chrome://newtab` and thus you can go back in history.

Comment: Careful with this because with a slow network connection you will hit the fallback url pretty regularly.

Comment: If you use this and you also prompt the user before leaving the page and the user opts to stay on the current page, the user will see the prompt twice (when there is history to return to). `window.history.go(-1)` will prompt them and they will cancel. Then the timeout will fire and ask them again. I haven't found a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 26):

Here is how i did it.

I used the **'beforeunload' event** to set a boolean. Then I set a timeout to watch if the 'beforeunload' fired.

```
var $window = $(window),
    $trigger = $('.select_your_link'),
    fallback = 'your_fallback_url';
    hasHistory = false;

$window.on('beforeunload', function(){
    hasHistory = true;
});

$trigger.on('click', function(){

    window.history.go(-1);

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!hasHistory){
            window.location.href = fallback;
        }
    }, 200);

    return false;
});
```

Seems to work in major browsers (tested FF, Chrome, IE11 so far).

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the question. You can easily replace `window.location.href = fallback` with `window.close()` and it works too.

Comment: This doesn't work with modern web apps, since browser back doesn't necessarily unload the page.

Answer (score 20):

There is a snippet I use in my projects:

```
function back(url) {
    if (history.length > 2) {
        // if history is not empty, go back:
        window.History.back();
    } else if (url) {
        // go to specified fallback url:
        window.History.replaceState(null, null, url);
    } else {
        // go home:
        window.History.replaceState(null, null, '/');
    }
}
```

FYI: I use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to manage browser history.

---

**Why to compare history.length to number 2?**

Because Chrome's startpage is counted as first item in the browser's history.

---

There are few possibilities of `history.length` and user's behaviour:

- User opens **new empty tab** in the browser and then runs a page. `history.length = 2` and we want to disable `back()` in this case, because user will go to empty tab.
- User opens the page in **new tab** by clicking a link somewhere before. `history.length = 1` and again we want to disable `back()` method.
- And finally, user lands at current page after **reloading few pages**. `history.length > 2` and now `back()` can be enabled.

---

**Note:** I omit case when user lands at current page after clicking link from external website without `target="_blank"`.

**Note 2:** `document.referrer` is empty when you open website by typing its address and also when website uses ajax to load subpages, so I discontinued checking this value in the first case.

Comment: This approach worked great for me. I actually store static fallback back links for my pages that I use on the fallback.

Comment: But, if you go back, the history.length won't change.. So, it doesn't work properly

Comment: Your're right, unfortunately. I use this snippet with "one-step-back" structure only…

Comment: This is incorrect.  For example, if you open a tab by middle-clicking a link, the new tab won't have any history.

Answer (score 19):

**this seems to do the trick:**

```
function goBackOrClose() {  

    window.history.back();
    window.close(); 

    //or if you are not interested in closing the window, do something else here
    //e.g. 
    theBrowserCantGoBack();

}
```

Call history.back() and then window.close(). If the browser is able to go back in history it won't be able to get to the next statement. If it's not able to go back, it'll close the window.

However, please note that if the page has been reached by typing a url, then firefox wont allow the script to close the window.

Comment: I've found this doesn't work unless I use a setTimeout with a delay of a few hundred milliseconds or so before trying to run the next statement, otherwise it'll run anyway after running history.back()

Comment: I haven't experienced that personally, which browser was it?

Comment: I had worked fine with setTimeout function in below answer.
ex: setTimeout(function() { window.close() }, 400);

Comment: `window.close()` is considered a security risk by many modern browsers. Some just wont let you do it.

Comment: you can do anything after  window.history.back(); window.close(); is just an example

Answer (score 19):

Be careful with `window.history.length` because it also includes entries for `window.history.forward()`

So you may have maybe `window.history.length` with more than 1 entries, but no history back entries.
This means that nothing happens if you fire `window.history.back()`

Answer (score 10):

You can't directly check whether the back button is usable. You can look at `history.length>0`, but that will hold true if there are pages *ahead* of the current page as well. You can only be *sure* that the back button is unusable when `history.length===0`.

If that's not good enough, about all you can do is call `history.back()` and, if your page is still loaded afterwards, the back button is unavailable! Of course that means if the back button *is* available, you've just navigated away from the page. You aren't allowed to cancel the navigation in `onunload`, so about all you can do to stop the back actually happening is to return something from `onbeforeunload`, which will result in a big annoying prompt appearing. It's not worth it.

In fact it's normally a Really Bad Idea to be doing anything with the history. History navigation is for browser chrome, not web pages. Adding “go back” links typically causes more user confusion than it's worth.

Comment: regarding length - not even then in all browsers. Some browsers count the current page as a history item and start at 1.  You'd have to include browser detection.

Comment: Actually I thought it was always `1`! The `0` was a brainfart, I thought browsers would always respond with `1` or more. Turns out Opera and IE think otherwise—good catch.

Comment: "History navigation is for browser chrome, not web pages" - Agreed

Answer (score 5):

`history.length` is useless as it does not show if user can go back in history.
Also different browsers uses initial values 0 or 1 - it depends on browser.

The working solution is to use `$(window).on('beforeunload'` event, but I'm not sure that it will work if page is loaded via ajax and uses pushState to change window history.

So I've used next solution:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
window.history.back();
setTimeout(function(){
    // if location was not changed in 100 ms, then there is no history back
    if(currentUrl === window.location.href){
        // redirect to site root
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Works for me like this:

function goBackOrTo(targetUrl){
 var currentUrl = window.location.href;
 window.history.go(-1);
 setTimeout(function(){
     // if location was not changed in 800 ms, then there is no history back
     if(currentUrl === window.location.href){
         // redirect to site root
         window.location.href = targetUrl;
     }
 }, 800);
}

Answer (score 5):

There are two properties in Navigation API that might help with it, but they are currently experimental.
canGoBack: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/canGoBack 
canGoForward: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/canGoForward

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033098/1945948) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651297/1945948). I think, the more conclusive answer is just to check if this is a new page in a new tab.

If the history of the page is more than one, then we can go back to the page previous to the current page. If not, the tab is a newly opened tab and we need to create a new tab.

Differently, to the answers linked, we are not checking for a `referrer` as a new tab will still have a referrer.

```
if(1 < history.length) {
    history.back();
}
else {
    window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me using react but can work in another case; when history is in the first page (you cannot go back) `window.history.state` will be null, so if you want to know if you can navigate back you only need:

```js
if (window.history.state == null) {
   //you cannot go back
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state):

> The `History.state` property returns a value representing the state at
> the top of the history stack. This is a way to look at the state
> without having to wait for a [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find a solution and this is the best i could get (but works great and it's the easiest solution i've found even here).

In my case, i wanted to go back on history with an back button, but if the first page the user opened was an subpage of my app, it would go back to the main page.

The solution was, as soon the app is loaded, i just did an replace on the history state:

```js
history.replaceState( {root: true}, '', window.location.pathname + window.location.hash)
```

This way, i just need to check `history.state.root` before go back. If true, i make an history replace instead:

```js
if(history.state && history.state.root)
    history.replaceState( {root: true}, '', '/')
else
    history.back()
```

Comment: I don't think there is other good use case. Maybe isn't an good idea If you want to check the history outside your app.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution will navigate back AND will tell if the navigation occurred or not:

```js
async function goBack() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => reject('nowhere to go'), 100);
    window.history.back();
    const onBack = () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onBack);
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBack);
      clearTimeout(timer);
      resolve(true);
    };
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onBack);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onBack);
  });
}

// usage
await goBack().catch(err => console.log('failed'));
```

How it works:

1. Try to navigate back
2. Add event listeners that will trigger on navigation to another website or to another page on the same site (SPA website, etc.)
3. If above events didn't occur in 100ms, deduce that there's nowhere to go back to

Notice that `goBack()` is an async function.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following approach. It utilizes the onbeforeunload event to detect whether the browser starts leaving the page or not. If it does not in a certain timespan it'll just redirect to the fallback.

```
var goBack = function goBack(fallback){
    var useFallback = true;

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
      useFallback = false;
    });

    window.history.back();

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (useFallback){ window.location.href = fallback; }
    }, 100); 
}
```

You can call this function using `goBack("fallback.example.org")`.

Comment: I like this the most, I just changed `windows.onbeforeunload` to event listener `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
 useFallback = false;
});` so it doesn't overwrite window.onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 1):

There is another *near* perfect solution, taken from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150398/2110948):

```
if( (1 < history.length) && document.referrer ) {
    history.back();
}
else {
    // If you can't go back in history, you could perhaps close the window ?
    window.close();
}
```

Someone reported that it does not work when using `target="_blank"` but it seems to work for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

the browser has back and forward button. I come up a solution on this question. but It will affect browser forward action and cause bug with some browsers.

It works like that:  If the browser open a new url, that has never opened, the history.length will be grow.

so you can change hash like

```
  location.href = '#__transfer__' + new Date().getTime()
```

to get a never shown url, then history.length will get the true length.

```
  var realHistoryLength = history.length - 1
```

but, It not always work well, and I don't known why ,especially the when url auto jump quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `window.history` in Angular for the FAQ on my site.

Whenever the user wants to exit the FAQ they can click the exit button (next to the back button)

My logic for this "exit" strategy is based on the entry ID and then just go back the number of states till that state.

So on enter:

```js
  enterState: { navigationId:number } = {navigationId: 1}

  constructor() {
    this.enterState = window.history.state
  }
```

*pretent the user navigates through the faq*

And then, when the user clicks the exit button, read the current state and calculate your delta:

```js
exitFaq() {
    // when user started in faq, go back to first state, replace it with home and navigate
    if (this.enterState.navigationId === 1) {
      window.history.go((window.history.state.navigationId - 1) * -1)
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
      //  non-angular
      //  const obj = {Title: 'Home', Url: '/'}
      //  window.history.replaceState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url)
    } else {
      window.history.go(this.enterState.navigationId - window.history.state.navigationId - 1)
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I also use a fallback for when the user started in the faq, in that case the `state.navigationId` is `1` and we want to route back, replace the first state and show the homepage (For this I'm using the Angular router, but you can use `history.replaceState` as well when you handle your own routes)

For reference:

- [history.go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go)
- [history.state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/state)
- [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)
- [Angular.router.navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```js
const prev = window.location.pathname;
window.history.back();
setTimeout(() => {
  if (prev === window.location.pathname) {
    // Do something else ... 
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular, I need to check if there is history, trigger location.back(), else redirect to parent route.

Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572533/18856708 works well.

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
}
...

back(): void {
    if (window.history.state === null) {
      this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
      return;
    }

    this.location.back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
function historyBack() {
  console.log('back');
  window.history.back() || window.history.go(-1);
  if (!window.history.length) window.close();
  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  setTimeout(function(){
    // if location was not changed in 100 ms, then there is no history back
    if(current === window.location.href){
        console.log('History back is empty!');
    }
  }, 100);
}
function historyForward() {
  console.log('forward');
  window.history.forward() || window.history.go(+1);
  var current = window.location.href;
  setTimeout(function(){
    // if location was not changed in 100 ms, then there is no history forward
    if(current === window.location.href){
        console.log('History forward is empty!');
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to check if the user is at the first place of the browser history stack, then execute custom logic

### Solution 1:

[navigation.canGoBack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/canGoBack) can solve the problem, but the compatibility with browsers is poor.

### Solution 2 (Recommended):

```
history.go(-1);
var timeout = 100;
var timer = setTimeout(() => {
  // If timeout occurs, execute your custom logic
}, timeout);

  // If the page is destroyed, clear the contingency plan
addEventListener('pageOnDestroy',()=>{
    window.clearTimeout(timer)
})
```

### Angular Instance

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, interval } from 'rxjs'
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-page',
  templateUrl: './test-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-page.component.scss']
})
export class TestPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  destroy = new Subject();

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy.next(null);
  }
  goback() {
    history.go(-1);

    interval(100)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(data => {
      // If there is no previous page, page destruction will not be triggered, close the page after timeout
      (window as any).javaobj?.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var fallbackUrl = "home.php";
if(history.back() === undefined)
    window.location.href = fallbackUrl;
```

Comment: this looks super easy?! is it tested on the various browsers?

Comment: in Chrome `history.back()` is `undefined` only on empty tab page

Answer (score -1):

### I found a JQuery solution that actually works

`window.history.length == 1`

This works on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.
You can use the following piece of JQuery code that worked for me on the latest versions of all of the above 3 browsers if you want to hide or remove a back button on your developed web page when there is no window history.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        if (window.history.length == 1) {
            $("#back-button").remove();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using a bit of PHP to achieve the result. It's a bit rusty though. But it should work.

```
<?php 
function pref(){ 
  return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? true : '';
}
?>
<html>
<body>

<input type="hidden" id="_pref" value="<?=pref()?>">

<button type="button" id="myButton">GoBack</button>

<!-- Include jquery library -->
<script> 
  if (!$('#_pref').val()) { 
    $('#myButton').hide() // or $('#myButton').remove()
  } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var func = function(){ console.log("do something"); };
if(document.referrer.includes(window.location.hostname) && history.length-1 <= 1){
    func();
}
else{
    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
    history.back();
    setTimeout(function(){
        currentUrl === window.location.href && func();
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

### Solution

```
'use strict';
function previousPage() {
  if (window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(({ length }) => length > 0).length > 0) {
    window.history.back();
  }
}
```

### Explaination

`window.location.pathname` will give you the current URI. For instance `https://domain/question/1234/i-have-a-problem` will give `/question/1234/i-have-a-problem`. See the documentation about [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) for more informations.

Next, the call to `split()` will give us all fragments of that URI. so if we take our previous URI, we will have something like `["", "question", "1234", "i-have-a-problem"]`. See the documentation about [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for more informations.

The call to `filter()` is here to filter out the empty string generated by the backward slash. It will basically return only the fragment URI that have a length greater than 1 (non-empty string). So we would have something like `["question", "1234", "i-have-a-question"]`. This could have been writen like so:

```
'use strict';
window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(function(fragment) {
  return fragment.length > 0;
});
```

See the documentation about [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) and the [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more informations.

Now, if the user tries to go back while being on `https://domain/`, we wont trigger the if-statement, and so wont trigger the `window.history.back()` method so the user will stay in our website. This URL will be equivalent to `[]` which has a length of `0`, and `0 > 0` is false. Hence, silently failing. Of course, you can log something or have another action if you want.

```
'use strict';
function previousPage() {
  if (window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(({ length }) => length > 0).length > 0) {
    window.history.back();
  } else {
    alert('You cannot go back any further...');
  }
}
```

### Limitations

Of course, this solution wont work if the browser do not support the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Check the documentation to know more about it before using this solution.

Answer (score -6):

I'm not sure if this works and it is completely untested, but try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function goBack() {
        history.back();
    }

    if (history.length > 0) { //if there is a history...
        document.getElementsByTagName('button')[].onclick="goBack()"; //assign function "goBack()" to all buttons onClick
    } else {
        die();
    }
</script>
```

And somewhere in HTML:

```
<button value="Button1"> //These buttons have no action
<button value="Button2">
```

### EDIT:

What you can also do is to research what browsers support the back function (I think they all do) and use the standard JavaScript browser detection object found, and described thoroughly, on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp). Then you can have 2 different pages: one for the "good browsers" compatible with the back button and one for the "bad browsers" telling them to go update their browser

Comment: `history.back` is a function. You want to check if `history.length > 0` then if it is go back with `history.back()`

Comment: Also `[]` on a NodeList makes no sense, and you can't assign a string to an event handler.

Answer (score -9):

Check if `window.history.length` is equal to 0.

Comment: Not a good way, since history.length does not tell you where you are in the history...

Comment: @Ron Reiter: Yes, I think the top answer and other comments for this question had already established that over a year ago...