# How can I return the number of history states available

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I am using [Ben Luptons's History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) in an iPad web app. When in full screen app mode I have a back button that when tapped calls `History.back();`

That works fine, unless you have run out of states to go back to. Essentially, on initial load, or if you hit back enough times to return to the original page that loaded.

I need to return the number of states available and only go back if there is one available. For example:

```
if( pagesAvailable > 0 )
    History.back();
```

I hope that makes sense and someone can offer some help

Thanks,

Will

Comment: Check this out, the correct answer is what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.history.length` returns the number of entries in the history object, according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

However, this appears to be unreliable as mentioned in the question @PRNDL linked to.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. The app I'm building is (for now) iPad only, so I can deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking the referrer?

```
if (document.referrer == "") {
    window.close()
} else {
    history.back()
}
```