# Backbone router getting history length for back-button

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, back-button, backbone-routing

I'm using Backbone inside a PhoneGap application. Like every mobile app I need a back-button functionality. It's basically working perfectly with Backbone, because I can simply use `window.history.back()` and it just works.

The only problem I have is to decide when to display the back button. Using `window.history.length` does not work, because it's not decremented when using `back()` (of course, because you can go `forward()` as well).

Is there any way to detect if there's more history or if I'm already at the bottom of the stack? Since the browser doesn't seem to supply this info ([How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)) does Backbone keep track of this maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casey Foster's answer looks nice on first sight, but has a flaw: When using `router.navigate` with `trigger` and `replace` both set to `true` you'll end up with a wrong counter.

I came up with a much simpler solution: Basically there's only one route where I don't need a back-button and that's the `index` route. Thus my code now looks like

```
Backbone.history.on('route', _.bind(function(router, route) {
    if(route === 'index') {
        this.$el.removeClass('has-back-button');
    } else {
        this.$el.addClass('has-back-button');
    }
}, this));
```

Comment: `index` -> `another page` -> `index`, you can't go back to `another page` via `window.history.back()` right?

Comment: You can only get to `index` using the back-button. Index contains a list. You open an item (and maybe sub-items) and use the back-button to get back to the list. So it works perfectly for my use case.

Comment: Hey if it satisfies your use case that's all you need then. A tip, if you're using BB >= 0.9.9, you can write `this.listenTo(Backbone.history, 'route', function (__, route) { ... });` without having to `_.bind` the function. This also makes event clean-up easy (and automatic in `View#remove`) with `this.stopListening()`.

Comment: @CaseyFoster Thanks, I almost forgot about `listenTo` (came across it once).

Answer (score 4):

You can implement something like this pretty easily

```
Backbone.history.length = 0;
Backbone.history.on('route', function () { ++this.length; });
myRouter.back = function () {
  Backbone.history.length -= 2;
  window.history.back();
};
```

And just use `myRouter.back()` to go back.

Comment: This is how I do it as well, and it works as long as you can control the back navigation. I doesn't work if the user can navigate backwards with the browser's native back button or a phone hardware button, though.

Comment: @casey-foster One problem: When using `{replace:true, trigger: true}` you're screwed

Comment: I used this solution in order to determine if the route was a brand new browser session/tab or not.  if (length) { /*existing browser tab session*/ } else { /* brand new browser tab session */ }

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@CaseyFoster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606634/backbone-router-getting-history-length-for-back-button/14607910#14607910), you can keep track of the history yourself. In addition to your own back button you need to catch the device's hardware Back-button press.

PhoneGap provides the [`backbutton`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton) event for this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
  Backbone.history.length -=2;
}, false);
```

Notice that `Backbone.history.length` is defined in Casey Foster's answer, it's not a part of Backbone itself.