# Go back or redirect to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using a back button for users to navigate back to the page they came from, problem is, if the user navigates there in a new tab or direct link, as they haven't "been anywhere" before they would get redirected back to a blank page.

Is there a solution for this? I'm thinking something like navigate back if possible, and if not it'll take you to a specific url.

This is what I have so far:

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;">Go back</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)

Comment: Personally, I think providing a message saying you can't go back would suffice. That's just my opinion. After the code part, this might go well on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ and ask what is preferred.

Comment: Apologies about duplicate, have flagged for removal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`document.referrer`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp)?
It's a hack and I do not recommend it since you'll not be maintaining post data (if any). If your page doesn't need to repost any data, then this should work.

```html
<a id="mylink" href="#">Go back</a>
```

```js
$('#mylink').click(function () {
    if (history.length == 0) {
        document.location = document.referrer;
    } else {
        history.go(-1);
    }
});
```

I must say that I agree with [SchautDollar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836680/go-back-or-redirect-to-url/14837037#comment20789559_14836680) - a message is a far better warning.

Comment: I tested this in Chrome when opening a new tab (middle click a link) and it kept the referrer. I'm not sure how standard this is though, there may be differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you could change link to:

```
echo '<a href="'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '">Go back</a>';
```

if not you can do the same with jQuery and javascript

```
document.location = document.referrer;
```

on the link click method.