# How can I tell if there is a `Back` state available without navigating?

Tags: javascript, html, history, html4

Is it possible to tell if there is a `back` state available (i.e. if the back button in the browser is clickable) without navigating?

I'd like to be able to do this in HTML4 and HTML5 if possible.

I can see there's `window.history.length`, but it doesn't seem to have coherent or consistent behaviour.

Is this possible?

I can see there is this thread, but it's rather old. Was wondering if there were HTML5 changes since this thread: [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history), it seems that when `window.history.length` is 1, the current page is the only page in history. Anything greater than 1 should mean that the user can navigate backwards. However this is only true for Firefox and Chrome. Looking at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_his_length.asp) it states

> Note: Internet Explorer and Opera start at 0, while Firefox, Chrome, and Safari start at 1.

So then anything greater than 0 in IE and Opera means that the user can navigate backwards.