# AngularJS: Disable html button if history is empty

Tags: angularjs, browser-history

In my AngularJS application I have implemented a html button with a "go back"-functionality . In case the history is empty (because the user hasn't changed the path since page load) I want to hide/disable it.

Is there a way to detect if the history is empty with angular?

Comment: Have you read about [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) service of Angularjs?

Comment: However, this question is a possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not).

Comment: In my opinion it's not, since the question is on how to do it "the angular-way".

Comment: Good question. Only one alert: I had problems with go back function, because it can vary and sometimes your user doesn't go to where you need. I prefer href with a fixed destination (like "#/home")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can even check [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service of angular js. It is completely same as window object of javascript.

> The history object contains the URLs visited by the user (within a
>   browser window).
>
> The history object is part of the window object and is accessed
>   through the window.history property.

If you want to see whether `history` is empty or not you should use

```
if( $window.history.length <= 1 ) {
  //Internet Explorer and Opera start at 0, while Firefox, Chrome, and Safari start at 1
  console.log("empty");
}
```

Please make sure you've injected `$window` service in your controller. Some couple of functions of history object are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). You can write more lines to detect browser first and after then apply your conditions in angular way. Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure, checking for history.length === 0 is sufficient in order to make sure there weren't any visited URLs in this window before? Just asking because I thought I read somewhere it wouldn't be sufficient. EDIT: I already found the answer in the MDN article you have linked to. "You can determine the number of pages in the history stack by looking at the value of the length property"

Comment: @tmuecksch please have a look on my edited answer. You can judge the history by using `<=1`. It will be good for all of the major browsers except IE or OPERA

Comment: Vineet: Good to know. Thanks.