# Browser back and forward button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have back and forward button in the application,and should behave in the same way as browser buttons. How to know currently browser button is enable/disable and based on that I can enabled or disabled buttons in my application.

Comment: what do you mean by the back button being disabled

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not

Comment: Need to map application back button with browser back button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)