# Perform action if window history for a site is empty

Tags: javascript

I have a Component that works as follows.

```
export default class BackButton extends Component {
  back() {
    window.history.back()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        icon={<ArrowLeft/>}
        onTouchTap={this.back.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

This works perfectly well, but there is an "edge case". If you pop from the stack enough, it might lead to being stuck at a certain state without being able to go back because the stack is empty. When that happens, I want to be able to perform some additional functionality and disable the back button.

```
<Button
  icon={<ArrowLeft/>}
  disabled={!hasMoreHistory}
  onTouchTap={this.back.bind(this)}
  onHistoryEmpty={() => callback ? callback() : Router.go('/')}
/>
```

Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Comment: Something like window.history.length?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as other SO question(s) point it out, **there is no reliable way of telling whether you can go back in your browser history or not**.

`window.history.length`

- does not contain a standardized value when you open up a fresh page(in chrome: `1`, in IE: `0`)
- might be `> 0` in the case when you may go forward

`window.history.previous` - in most cases is `undefined`

See: 
[How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)