# Hiding Back Button in Web App

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm creating an app for iPhone, which is a browser window within the app. Now, since there is no back button, I programmed the following to show one, which works fine:

```
<head>
...
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
 <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</body>
```

I would like to hide the button on the first page, as it messes up its design. Is there a way to do this, possibly by checking that there is no history or back page available.

I've looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not), but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I should add that this question is not necessarily related to creating the app. The same technique should apply ot a regular webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  I think your document should look like this..

```
<button class="btn" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

and in the head on JUST the page where you DO NOT want the button to show, include a style tag

```
<style>
.btn {
display: none;
} '
```

then, in your CSS doc

```
.btn {
display: block;
}
```

The style tag in your HEAD will override the CSS.

I decided to use 'display' instead of 'visibility' because display will the button from taking up space.  While visibility will take up the space but just won't display the button.  I guess leaving a blank square.

I hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Put the button in a DIV and use the following in the CSS

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind elaborating a little as to how to include it in the code exactly, i.e. how to put the visibility in a conditional way.

Comment: Sure.  I added a new answer.  Thought of a better idea.