# How to check if the user can go forward in browser history or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want using JavaScript to see if there is history or not

I mean if the forward button is available on the browser or not

How can I do it?

Comment: `history` object might help you.

Comment: No because of security concerns.

Comment: I need a specific answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't add a comment, but there's a good discussion in the following link:
[How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)
which I think is very similar, and indicates that you can't.

Edit: The only way I found is calling `history.forward()` and check if it returns `undefined`, although obviously, it would move the user forward if it was possible, and this is probably not really effective depending on your use case!

Comment: I had read it. It's no help me. My question is different. I want to check if the forward button disable or no

Comment: @mosestoh I edited the answer, although this is the only way I found, it's not effective.