# Page load from browser back button click

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-history, html5-history

Is there a way to detect if the page load occurred from clicking the browser back button?

I have to take a different action on page load if it was due to user landing on the page by hitting the browser back button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)

Comment: Different. That question is to determine if the user can go back in history. I wanted to find out if the current page load happened for the user hitting the back button or not.