# History back if exist in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, browser-history

I want to back in history if exist in  Angular 7.*?
I used the following:

```
  import { Location } from '@angular/common';

    constructor(private location: Location) {

  }

    get isBackHistoryExist(): boolean {
    return window.history.length > 1;
  }
  back(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

But `window.history.length > 1` is always true !

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not