# How can i hide the back button in my site when there is no back URL available using JS / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've back button in my site and i want to hide, if there is no back URL available(i.e from my site). i used `history` of JS to check `history.length` and `go()` for back to previous URL. To check back URL is from my site or not i used

```
var prev_url = document.referrer;
if(prev_url.indexOf(window.location.origin) === -1){
  // hide back button
}
```

which is working fine but `document.referrer` is changed if i clicked other link in my site and if i go back to previous page then the `document.referrer` is referring forwarded link which i don't want. i want current opened page previous URL not referrer URL. if anyone have any other option than `document.referrer` this let me know plz.

If have any other solution.. will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't hide back button It's part of browser interface.

Comment: i didn't mean browsers back button. its from my site/application

Comment: Is this solve your problem [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3588315/387194)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if anything works for me. It's exacts same condition which i want to handle.