# Check if there is a previous page in vue route

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using `$router.go(-1)` to go back to the previous page but as I am using this on a home page I want know how to check if there is a previous route.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vue router navigation is tracked by the native browser [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length), use `window.history.length`.

If it is `0` there is nothing to go back to.

**However**; Users arriving from another website have a value higher than `0`.

To overcome this issue, upon your `App` mounting; store the initial value of `window.history.length` globally.

Capture the initial value using a mount hook such as: `beforeMount` or `mounted`.

Store the history length value using `$root` as a global state:

```js
this.$root.historyCount = window.history.length
```

> Alternatively use `VueX` if you are already leveraging the store bus plugin.

When checking history state on a call to action, subtract `$root.historyCount` from `window.history.length` to see if zeroes out.

This way you will be only counting the history that occurs in your own app.

You may also want to consider that perhaps if your current route (`$router.currentRoute`) is the home page there is also no way of going back beyond that page but obviously will prevent back navigation to prior home revisits.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional possible issues you may encounter.

Comment: History length seems to be capped at 20 (at least in Chrome) so this doesn't always work. Also, cloning isn't necessary because the length is a primitive.

Comment: `window.history.length` is a primitive (number). Why cloning...? I mean, you would need to clone `window.history`, which is an object, but `window.history.length`...?

Comment: Isn't there a vue router built in method for this?

Comment: Back in 2020 something was making `window.history` a nested reactive reference hance the clone method, I do not know if this was intentional in an old version or was a brief bug at the time, whatever was going on I saw unexpected behaviour of the entry value changing as I navigated, but this seems to have been long since resolved so I have taken that out of the sample.

Answer (score 1):

As window.history.length will always return 1.
You can use

```
if (window.history.state.back === null) {
 router.push({path="/"}); //or whichever path you required
} else {
 router.back();
}
```

Comment: `window.history.length` does not always return 1.

Comment: The property returns at least 1, because the list includes the current page. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_his_length.asp