# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined for history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some filters on page. Once I click on back I want to go back to filtered page one by one.

Like I am on page and I have 3 filters on it. I applied filter 1 and then filter 2. Once I click on back I should go to filter1 page , then the main page. But it is not working. once I click on back, it is showing
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const backBtn = ({ href }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    if (href) {
      history.push(href);
    } else {
      history.go(-1);
    }
  }

  return(
    <button onClick={handleClick}> Back
    </button>

  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the user can go back in browser history or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here :-

- The component name should start with capital letter like `BackBtn`.
- The `useHistory` hook will return valid `history` object only if `BackBtn` is a child of a `Router` component which you imported from `react-router-dom` (Can be `BrowserRouter`,`HashRouter` etc). Currently `history` is `undefined` which means `BackBtn` is not a child of `Router` component.

Here is a sandbox which works :-

[image: Edit react-router-useHistory-stackoverflow]

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined for history.go(-1)
```

means history is undefined. Try using useHistory function in your app.js and adding history as a prop.