# Browser's Navigation arrows status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to track browser navigation arrow's status, Like is it enabled or disabled

[image]

Basically i want to know whether back navigation is possible or not from the current page, so i tried with history.length but since it considers forward history as well its not working as expected,

So, I'm trying this new approach in react js by tracking the browser's back arrow status whether its enabled  [image] or disable [image] but no luck so far,

There some solution on web which i tried but didn't get the expected output like , (document.referrer == "") and (history.previous) and length as i mentioned above, so that's the reason i'm trying this approach.

can anyone help me out with this is one, like is there anyway using which i can track whether the back arrow is enable (back navigation is possible) or its disabled (back navigation not possible) in browser

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588420/15622190

Comment: Thanks but most of the solutions given there i already tried and doesn't seems to work

Comment: Well, as that other answer states: you pretty much *can't.* It's not something your website should concern itself with. It should be stateless. What are you trying to do with that information to begin with?

Comment: there is back navigation button on the website so based on back history i need to hide and show that button