# How to emulate browser back button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Page history - back button exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982254/page-history-back-button-exists)

I need to have a link in some pages of a website, by clicking on it, it needs to go back to the previous page, just like the browser's back button. What is the right way to do that? I'm thinking that I should use some client side scripting like Javascript, right?

Comment: Dups: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=history+back+javascript&submit=search

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In JavaScript, it's:

```
history.go(-1);
```

or

```
history.back();
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use

```
history.go(-1);
```

But you cannot go forward anymore after that (so the Forward button doesn't bring you back to where you were -- i.e., this is not 100% the same as clicking the Back button).

Comment: In order to got forward you have to use `back()` instead of `go(-1)`. After a call to `back()` you can use `forward()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Zurück" name="back" onClick="javascript:history.back(1)">
</form>
```

Or within a link:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back(1)">back</a>
```

If you want to go forward afterwards, use `history.forward(1)`, but be aware: this only works if you called `back()` before!

Comment: Freedom to use events however we want!

Answer (score 4):

Clicking on button takes browser back

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Go Back" ONCLICK="history.back()">
```

Comment: Death to inline click events!

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
<script>
function goBack()
{
  window.history.back()
}
</script>
```

should do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the History API for browsers.

```
window.history.back()
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<FORM><INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Go Back" 
ONCLICK="history.go(-1)"></FORM>
```

Try this code