# create button behave as apage back

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a ASP.Net page which includes a search input

1. search input takes a value
2. button fills a table with data
3. each data has a link button to go to another page
4. when I press this link I can go to the another page
5. when I press back button of the browser it return me again to the search page and the search input still saved the value

I need to create a button when I click it behave as browser back button.

Comment: onclientclick="javascript:window.history.back()"

Comment: Already voted to close for another reason, but this is also a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490407/how-to-emulate-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history.go(-1)` or `history.back()`

Here is a link you may find helpful: [How to emulate browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490407/how-to-emulate-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: Next time, instead of pulling an answer directly from the SO post you referenced, flag the newer post as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Will do, thanks @CubeJockey. Still new at this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back();" />
```

This input tag will go back in the Browser history by one page unless there isn't anything in the history to go back to.