# Add possibility to go back in history in new site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a website (e.g. `www.foo.com`) and redirect to another (e.g. `www.bar.com`) via `window.location`. Unfortunately the website runs in fullscreen-mode (so no address bar available) and the user interacts with it by touch inputs (no keyboard, no mouse).
Is it somehow possible to go back from `www.bar.com` to `www.foo.com`? Does jQuery do the trick?

UPDATE 1:

My problem is, that I dont have any access to `www.bar.com`.
`history.back();` works fine, but I cannot just add another button to the 
foreign website, can I?

To be more exact:
I refer from my website to `www.google.com`. How can I go back from `www.google.com` to my website?
If you advise me to use `history.back()` in the other website (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490407/how-to-emulate-browser-back-button-using-javascript)), please tell me how

I am very thankful

Comment: Can you store the location in a variable based on user events, and then simply navigate based on the location in the variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to emulate browser back button using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490407/how-to-emulate-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

did you try `window.history.back();` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. The probelm is, I don't have any access to ´www.bar.com´. I think, I didn't ask clear enough, what my problem is

Comment: well when user is on a new webpage, then i don't think there is any chance for the first page to do anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `document.referrer` It returns the URI of the page that linked to this page. [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp)