# Conditionally use window.history.back(-1) if previous page is not from the same domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am currently building a site using **React** and **GatsbyJS** and trying to conditionally add a navigation `window.history.back(-1);` if the previous page was part of the same domain.

An example is

```
navigateBack = () => {
  if (window !== undefined) {
    window.history.back(-1);
  }
};
```

note that `if (window !== undefined)` allows `window` to be used without server side rendering.

How can I check the previous page before running this function.

For example is the user navigated from a external link I want to use `navigate('/stories/')`, else if the user came from an internal page, i.e. `'/stories/2/'` I want them to go back using `window.history.back(-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby has an [api](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onRouteUpdate) that'll tell you the previous location. Perhaps you can use it together with `document.referrer` like @ATT suggested to check if previous url were from the same domain.

```
// gatsby-browser.js

exports.onRouteUpdate = ({ location, prevLocation }) => {
  if (prevLocation || document.referrer.includes(SITE_NAME)) {
    // same domain
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to have previous location information in your React component, check out the answers to [this other gatsby question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942047/how-to-get-previous-url-in-react-gatsby/54950614#54950614).

Side note: `document.referrer` will be blank (`""`) instead of `null` or `undefined` if there were no referrer (site omit referrer, or direct)

Answer (score 4):

I've had to address this by checking to make sure there's a history to go to, and then by verifying that the current host can be found in the referrer. If those are found then I know they came from within my site, so I go back; otherwise, I navigate them elsewhere.

```
if(window.history.length > 1 && 
document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) !== -1) {
  window.history.back();
}
else {
  <do something else>
}
```

Comment: I understand there are security tools (AV) that will strip the referrer from every request. Or even browser security settings. How do you get around this? Or is it such an edge case you dont worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of the previous page by `document.referrer`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you perhaps elaborate? Using `navigateBack = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      if (document.referrer.includes(config.siteUrl)) {
        window.history.back(-1);
      } else {
        navigate('/stories/');
      }
    }
  };` as per your suggestion but when `console.log(document.referrer);` nothing is shown in the console... it's not `null` nor `undefined` just blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router, you can use the following snippet.

```
if(browserHistory.getCurrentLocation().key === null) {
   browserHistory.push(customRoute); // push to custom route
} else {
   browserHistory.go(-1); // go back normally
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use Reach-Router but yes this is how I would do it if not.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here for a version that works also when the window is "new" and the referrer might not be reliable https://stackoverflow.com/a/68161306/1348517